# Tridion 2009 C# : How To add a custom Schema name space

Tags: 2009, schema, c#

I'm creating a web service in C# for Tridion 2009. This web service creates a schema in Tridion based on an XML input file. The schema gets created just fine. But I can't seem to change the schema namespace. I would like to do this on the moment that I create or update the schema.

From:

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="uuid:C5F06CAA-7C03-40CD-A857-351098D7DD99"
```

To:

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://namespace.mynamespace.nl/content/generiek/1.0"
```

I'm creating the schema as follows:

```
schema = (Schema)tdse.GetNewObject(Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDSDefines.ItemType.ItemTypeSchema, folderID, publicationID);
            schema.Title = CreateSlugTitle(schema_title_prefix + portletProviderID);
            schema.Description = portletProviderID;
CreateFragmentSchemaFields(schema, tdse, fieldName, fieldType, fieldMandatory, fieldLable);
   protected void CreateFragmentSchemaFields(Schema schema, Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDS.TDSE tdse, string fieldName, string fieldType, Boolean fieldMandatory, string fieldLable)
{
    var schemaField = schema.Fields;

    switch (fieldType)
    {
        case "text":
            fieldName = "fragment_text." + CreateSlugTitle(fieldName);
            schema.Fields.AddNew(fieldName);
            schemaField[fieldName].MaxOccurs = 1;
            schemaField[fieldName].FieldType = EnumTridionWebSchemaFieldType.FieldTypeFormatText;
            schemaField[fieldName].Description = fieldLable;
            schemaField[fieldName].FilterXSLT = "";
            schemaField[fieldName].Size = 5;

            if (fieldMandatory)
            {
                schemaField[fieldName].MinOccurs = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                schemaField[fieldName].MinOccurs = 0;
            }
            break;
        case "link":
            embeddedSchema = (Schema)tdse.GetObject(embeddedLinkSchemaID, EnumOpenMode.OpenModeView, null, XMLReadFilter.XMLReadAll);
            fieldName = "fragment_link." + CreateSlugTitle(fieldName);
            schema.Fields.AddNew(fieldName);
            schemaField[fieldName].Description = fieldLable;
            schemaField[fieldName].FieldType = EnumTridionWebSchemaFieldType.FieldTypeEmbed;
            schemaField[fieldName].EmbeddedSchema = embeddedSchema;

            if (fieldMandatory)
            {
                schemaField[fieldName].MinOccurs = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                schemaField[fieldName].MinOccurs = 0;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 and thanks for joining us on Tridion Stack Exchange. An edit from Frank van Puffelen is a good sign, too. Hey, I recognize that logo! ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `NamespaceURI` property but unfortunately it's read-only.
So it looks like you will need to use `UpdateXML` to set it. For that, you would probably have to specify the full XSD -- so you might want to do that after updating all of the fields.

Comment: Thanks Peter, the NameSpaceURI is read-only in deed. i was hoping there would be a better alternative then updating the XML.

Answer (score 2):

A Quick Try tells me it's not going to work. the namespace gets replaced but the the schema cant be saved.

```
            //TEST TO CHANGE THE ROOTNAMESPACEURI            
        string changeNameSpace = schema.GetXML(XMLReadFilter.XMLReadAll);
        string NameSpaceID = string.Empty;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(changeNameSpace, "uuid[\\w\\:\\-]+(\")"))
        {
            NameSpaceID = m.Value.Replace("uuid", "");
            NameSpaceID = m.Value.Replace("\"", "");
            Logger(NameSpaceID);
            changeNameSpace = changeNameSpace.Replace(NameSpaceID, "http://namespace.mywebsite.nl/content/generiek/1.0");
            changeNameSpace = changeNameSpace.Replace("<tcm:NamespaceURI>" + NameSpaceID + "</tcm:NamespaceURI>", "<tcm:NamespaceURI>http://namespace.mywebsite.nl/content/generiek/1.0</tcm:NamespaceURI>");
            changeNameSpace = changeNameSpace.Replace("xmlns=\"" + NameSpaceID + "\"", "xmlns=\"http://namespace.mywebsite.nl/content/generiek/1.0\"");
            Logger(NameSpaceID);
        }

        Logger("xml out: " + changeNameSpace + " end xml out ");
        schema.UpdateXML(changeNameSpace);
```

ERROR:
    CDATA[It is not possible to change the NamespaceURI of a Schema]